# How can a component be scaled without occupying 100% of its original space, utilizing only the necessary new scaled space?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

Im using tailwind css to style my components in a reactJS project using the mui components lib. What Im trying to do is to scale a reusable component to 90% of its original size, but when the component is rendered, visually it only takes 90% but in reality the space this component is taking is 100% of its original size.

This is the parent tag where Im applying the scaling:

```js
<Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      className={`rounded-lg p-2 bg-red-500 w-80 sm:w-96 ${scale && scale}` }
>
       .....
</Grid>
```

This is the code for when Im using the component:

```js
<Grid container className="justify-center" xs={12} sm={6}>
    <MyComponent {...items[0]} scale="scale-90" />
 </Grid>
```

I've tried wrapping the parent Grid tag in a div tags and applying properties to it but none of them worked:

Approach 1:

```js
<div className={clsx("inline-flex", scale)}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        className="rounded-lg p-2 bg-red-500 w-80 sm:w-96"
      >
        {/* ... rest of the component code */}
      </Grid>
 </div>
```

Approach 2:

```js
< div
style = {
    {
      transform: `scale(${scale})`,
      transformOrigin: 'top left',
      width: scale * 100 + '%',
      height: scale * 100 + '%',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    }
  } >
  <
  Grid
container
direction = "column"
className = {
    `rounded-lg p-2 bg-red-500 w-80 sm:w-96 overflow-hidden`
  } >
  { /* ... rest of the component code */ } <
  /Grid> <
  /div>
```

Is what Im trying to do even possible ? that I scale a component and the size that it takes is also = to the scaled size, if this doesnt work please suggest another method